# TypeScript in React: 'No Overload Matches this Call' when using optional function parameters in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to create 2 types of switches, one of which will need access to the click event. I have interfaced my props as follows:

```
interface SectionProps {
    title: string;
    options: {
        flavorText: string;
        toggle: (e?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
        checked: boolean;
    };
    inputStyle: SelectionsType;
    /**an array of desired tile displays if using tile inputs */
    tileLabels?: string[];
}
```

and I am passing the toggle function either onChange (for the checkbox input) or onClick (for my tile inputs, which are div's) as follows:

```
                {inputStyle === 'checkbox' && (
                    <Switch
                        type="checkbox"
                        onChange={options.toggle}
                        checked={options.checked}
                    ></Switch>
                )}
                {inputStyle === 'tiles' && (
                    <TileSwitch
                        isActive={options.checked}
                        onClick={e => options.toggle(e)}
                    >
                        {tileLabels?.map((tile, i) => (
                            <TileName key={i}>{tile}</TileName>
                        ))}
                    </TileSwitch>
                )}
```

I only need the event passed for the tile inputs, so I made the event parameter optional with the `e?` argument in the interface. However, I am getting an error on the `onChange` prop for `<Switch>` saying `No overload matches this call.` with a longlist of errors, eventually saying `Type '(e?: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent> | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void'`

I'm unsure why onChange is expecting to receive the event argument when it is optional. Is there a better approach to passing function params optionally through the interface?

Comment: This is a common error, but in almost all cases, you want to define the callback with required parameters.  You do not need to pass all of the parameters when you use it.

Comment: But more critically, you have a mismatch of the event type between `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` and `MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>`

Comment: When you write this: `onChange={options.toggle}`, the toggle function will be called with the `onChange` event.  If you want it called with no arguments, write this instead: `onChange={() => options.toggle()}`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Ahh, this makes sense, so this way I am specifying that I want the toggle function called, but specifically without the optional event being passed through the interface. Thank you so much, that was the issue it looks like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition `toggle: (e?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;` says that `toggle` can be called with 0 or 1 arguments.  If it is called with one argument, that argument must be of type `React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>`.

The `onChange` property of `Switch` will be called with one argument, which is the change event of the switch. When you pass a function to `onChange` like this: `<Switch onChange={options.toggle} />`, you are telling the `Switch` to call `options.toggle` with its change event.

So you get the error that you've posted, because the `Switch` component is calling `options.toggle` with an event of type `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, which is not an acceptable argument for `options.toggle`, which can only accept events of type `React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>`.

In order to call the callback with no arguments, you want to write this instead: `<Switch onChange={() => options.toggle()} />`.  This ignores the event argument and prevents it from being passed.

Comment: One last question, now that I'm able to access the clicked `div` through event.target, I'm struggling to access the `innerHTML` value as well, being told that property innerHTML doesn't exist on event target. Is there a specific way in react to access the div's inner html, or children? Event is returning a class from what I can see, and event.target is returning the specific `div` element, but that's all I seem to be able to access.

Comment: try using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` and see if that helps.

Comment: Is it that `innerHTML` doesn't exist on the `div` or that you can't access `innerHTML` because the `div` might be `undefined`?  In that case, use an `if` to make sure you've got  a valid target.

Comment: Looks like `currentTarget` was the correct approach, I appreciate you helping out with such simple issues!

Comment: No worries!  The `e.currentTarget` vs. `e.target` distinction is something I've only recently learned and I've been using React for years.